CronJob triggering twice
I have a Django-based application that triggers a cron job to generate and send daily report emails. However, the recipients are encountering an issue where they receive two emails instead of one. One email contains the correct data, while the other is sent with an empty template.
The application uses Brevo (formerly Sendinblue) for mailing, and the email templates are linked via a template_id and parameters passed from the back-end. The application is deployed on an EC2 instance.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far to troubleshoot the issue:
Testing on Staging Environment: When tested in the staging environment, the emails are sent correctly, with only one email being delivered.
Template Recreation: I recreated the email template to rule out template-specific issues, but the problem persists in the production environment. 


Did you submit a query to Brevo ?
If so, what was the answer ?
Add links
